# Struts 2 filed names with dots in their names

Tags: struts2, ognl

Consider the posted data has dot in its name ex: `fromAccount.accountNo`. If we write a custom `validator` like

```java
@CustomValidator(type = "AccountBelongsToUserValidator", fieldName = "fromAccount.accountNo")
```

And write the `AccountBelongsToUserValidator` like below :

```java
  public void validate(Object object) throws ValidationException {

    String fieldName = getFieldName();
    Object value = this.getFieldValue(fieldName, object);
```

The `value` will be `null`.

Is it possible that struts/ognl can read fields which have dot in their names. I used `formAccount\\.accountNo` try to escape dot but it did not help ?!

The relative action is not `ModelDriven`.

Comment: How does your object look like? Do you have getter/setter for all properties?

Answer (score 1):

In OGNL '.' has a special meaning and it means a property reference. So if you have an object referenced by `fromAccount` and it has a property `accountNo` then you can access this property by `fromAccount.accountNo`. It is also used with projection, selection, subexpression evaluation, and method call. You can't escape this character, because OGNL has not escape operator. However you can use this simbol '.' as a char literal. OGNL also supports all character escapes:

> Character literals, also as in Java: delimited by single-quotes, also with the full set of escapes;

OGNL referencing objects by name like in Java, in Java names are [alphanumeric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphanumeric).

Comment: Thanks. I tried to use `fromAccount\\u002EaccountNo` but did not worked (`\\u002E` instead of `.`). I thought may be I got some thing wrong. So I try to test a simple filed with name `aSampleNo` and replace the `o` with `\u006F`. The `aSampleN\\u006F` works perfect and the `getFieldValue` can gets its value